# Restrict file upload to just jpegs with php

Tags: php

Please can someone help? I have the following code which uploads a file to my server and renames it to whoever the logged in user is. For example the user 'coca-cola-lover' uploads a jpeg - the script would also rename the jpeg 'coca-cola-lover.jpg'.

My problem is that I need it to limit the upload to just jpegs - and also limit the file size to 2mb.

Please help - I was trying to find a solution all night.

Thanks in advance

```
    // Your file name you are uploading
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
$username = $row_Recordset1['username'];

$ext = end(explode('.', $file_name));

$renamed_file_name = $username;

$new_file_name=$renamed_file_name.'.'.$ext;

//set where you want to store files
//in this example we keep file in folder upload
//$new_file_name = new upload file name
//for example upload file name cartoon.gif . $path will be upload/cartoon.gif
$path= "../sites/images/users/".$new_file_name;
if($ufile !=none)
{
if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path))
{
echo "Successful<BR/>";

//$new_file_name = new file name
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'] = file size
//$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'] = type of file
echo "File Name :".$new_file_name."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size']."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type']."<BR/>";
}
else
{
echo "Error";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) tells you what format the file is in

as per bgy's comment, you should also force the file extension to be what you want:

```
 $new_file_name=$renamed_file_name.'.'.$ext; // wrong, uses data from the client

 $new_file_name=$renamed_file_name.'.jpg';   // ok, just what we want
```

never trust and never use filenames provided by the client.

Comment: You can't rely on getimagesize() because if you inject some php code into a binary image and rename it to 3vil.php you'll be able to execute the embed php code.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice. I guess this is in addition to restricting what can be uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `exif_imagetype`:

```
<?php
    if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        die(The picture is not a gif');
    }
```

For details see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Comment: So where would I put this in my code? I have tried but it just returns an error. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to make sure that the **exif extension** is enabled in php.ini or built in during compilation. Use `phpinfo()` to check for its existence.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the four to detect a mimetype of the file:

- [finfo_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) (by default enabled as of 5.3)
- [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) (requires enabled GD)
- [exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) (requires enabled Exif)
- [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) (deprecated as of 5.3)

You can also limit the [MimeType from the FileUpload element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/accept), but since this is client-side code, it can easily be removed by malicious users (and it's also buggy across browsers):

```
<input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" accept="image/jpeg"/>
```

For further information on how to [handle file uploads with PHP (including limiting file size), check the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

There is also [a lot of very similar questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mime+upload+size+php) already, one being:

- [Check picture file type and size before file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249943/check-picture-file-type-and-size-before-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You restrict the size via the [normal mechanisms](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), but you'll need to use the [fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) to determine the filetype after uploading.

Answer (score 1):

A few advices for the current code

1. Use `$_FILES` instead of `$HTTP_POST_FILES`.
2. If you need to get file extensions use `$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`.
3. Use [`is_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) and [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).
4. Don't relay on `$_FILES['file']['type']` - it can be modified by user.
5. Indent your code.

If you want to limit file upload to the following requirements:

1. Filesize: max 2mb.
2. File type: `image/jpeg`

Do something like that:

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (file_is_uploaded($tmpName) {
    $filesize = fielsize($tmpName);
    $mimeType = exif_imagetype('image.gif');

    if ($filesize <= 2 * 1024 * 1024 && $mimeType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
         $filename = $USERNAME . '.jpg';
         if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filename) == false)  {
             // sth goes wrong
         }
    } else {
         die('Invalid.');
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good - but not sure how to adapt my original code to rename as the username and where it should upload to. Are you able to help further? Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks again. i'm still lost. i'm new to php and mysql so i'm determined to get this to work. I have added '$username = $row_Recordset1['username'];' to the code you wrote but am not sure where to set the upload path '../sites/images/users/'

Comment: `$filename` - this should be the path where uploaded file will be stored on your server. So if you need to save it in `../sites/images/users/` add this path before `$username`.

Comment: brilliant. thanks i'll give that a whirl whem i'm at home tonight. thanks again for your help. it's very much appreciated.

Comment: also - how do you add code when writing comments here on stack overflow?

Comment: The same way as in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (Code Spans section).